# remote_form_for in rails with the :with option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, link-to-remote

Is it possible to use the :with option with remote_form_for?

It works with link_to_remote, and the api docs seems to indicate :with should work with any of the remote_ methods.

Here is the code I'm using, and output it's producing:

### Link_to_remote (works):

```
 = link_to_remote 'ARGH', {:url => {:action => 'load_item', :id => @policy.id} , :with => "'elephant=mouse'"}

 <a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Request('http://localhost:3000/quote_edit/load_item/5', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'elephant=mouse' + '&amp;authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('o6whEDZLuq1b1NsuZXIlNjc3iudZNC8jU+ZxgUDXFUk=')}); return false;">arg</a>
```

### Remote_form_for (doesn't work)

```
  = remote_form_for :policy, @policy, :url => {:action => 'load_item', :id => @policy.id} , :with => "'elephant=mouse'" do |f|

    <form action="http://localhost:3000/quote_edit/load_item/5" method="post" onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('http://localhost:3000/quote_edit/load_item/5', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;">
```

Does anyone know how to make remote_form_for pick up on this option?

Or is it being ignored by remote_form_for as it needs to use `parameters:Form.serialize(this)` to pick up the values from the current form?

Cheers
Dave Smylie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I wanted to use javascript to calculate the id of the url.

Researched the source code and determined that remote forms and submits don't seem to allow the :with statement to work.

I got around this using a hidden field called overridden_id on the form.  Then in the :before option, I added javascript to set the hidden fields value.

Inside the controller I added "params[:overriden_id] || parmam[:id]" to my Find to override the default id passed into the url.